# Convert .sql to .bak

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a database in MySQL and I need a backup of it in .bak file. I found numerous topics about converting .bak to .sql, but none about .sql to .bak. Is it doable? And if so - how?

Answer (score 2):

`*.bak` extension file's are a SQL Server backup file and `*.sql` is a sql script file which contains plain SQL commands.

You can't just convert a *.sql file to *.bak.

Probably what you want to do is: restore the backup file and then import it to MYSQL.

This is how you restore *.bak file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Then import it to mysql:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,72796,72796